# Unable to schedule a task using schtasks.exe within the SetupComplete.cmd script on Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I have a requirement to automate Windows 10 deployments for my client. I make use of the SetupComplete.cmd function to connect to the corp wifi and install MSI's. There are some EXE installs which I am unable to run silently, and so my intention is to copy the install files to a local drive and set a scheduled task, using the command schtasks.exe, to run a script at next login to complete the remaining installs.

The script successfully connects to the wifi, installs the msi's and copies the files to the local drive. The scheduled task however is not setup.

If I run the SetupComplete.cmd script on the machine once the user is logged in, all functions including the scheduled task creation complete successfully.

I specified the exact folder path of schtasks (windir/system32) and ran from there. Works when ran manually, not from setupcomplete.cmd.

I have tried copying the schtasks.exe to the install media and calling the program from it (in case the exe has not been written at the time of the script running, which I doubt)

I have placed the task as the final step and included a sleep for 20 seconds prior to its execution.

I enabled logging and the command runs, but there is no acknowledgement of the request. With echo off there is no result given. With echo on, the line is printed with no result.

I removed all other commands from my SetupComplete script and ran with just the schtasks.exe command, just in case it doesnt play nice with other commands, and this still didnt work. I have seen other forums using schtasks.exe in their SetupCmplete scripts as a solution to some requirements so it seems it can work if used correctly.

I am aware that the script at this stage is ran under the System account but cant find any mention of this not being able to run with these permissions.

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE= D:\test\batch.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG

netsh wlan add profile filename="D:\Blah.xml"

netsh wlan connect name=An interface="WiFi"

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d D:\bkgrnd\blah.bmp /f
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters

REM         ***MSI INSTALLS***
msiexec.exe /i "D:\MSI\3t.msi" /quiet /norestart /L*V "D:\MSI\logs\3TLog.log"
msiexec.exe /i "D:\MSI\Chrome.msi" /quiet /norestart /L*V "D:\MSI\logs\ChromeLog.log"
msiexec.exe /i "D:\MSI\FireFox.msi" /quiet /norestart /L*V "D:\MSI\logs\FFLog.log"
msiexec.exe /i "D:\MSI\node.msi" /quiet /norestart /L*V "D:\MSI\logs\nodeLog.log"
msiexec.exe /i "D:\MSI\Slack.msi" /quiet /norestart /L*V "D:\MSI\logs\SlackLog.log"
msiexec.exe /i "D:\MSI\fs-windows-agent-2.5.0.msi" /quiet /norestart /L*V "D:\MSI\logs\FreshService.log"

REM Copy install files and create scheduled task to complete installs of BD and CB
mkdir C:\FinalInstalls
mkdir C:\FinalInstalls\BD
mkdir C:\FinalInstalls\CB
xcopy "D:\EXE\setupdownloader_[astring].exe" C:\FinalInstalls\BD
xcopy D:\EXE\CB\Setup.exe C:\FinalInstalls\CB
xcopy D:\EXE\CB\settings.ini C:\FinalInstalls\CB
xcopy D:\finalinstalls.cmd C:\FinalInstalls
schtasks /create /tn "FinalInstalls" /tr "cmd.exe /k C:\FinalInstalls\finalinstalls.cmd" /sc ONLOGON /RL HIGHEST
```

I would expect the task to show in task scheduler as it does when I run it manually. I cant think of another way around this and it seems to have worked for other people. Any help would be very appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not start your programs hidden. This VBScript starts notepad hidden `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """c:\windows\notepad.exe""", 0, false`
`

Comment: PS `MKDIR` makes intermediate directories so your first `mkdir` is unnecessary. Plus `copy` is the correct command to use not `xcopy`. Copy is internal and is for coping one or more files in a directory. It involves NO program starts. `XCopy` is for copying files by criteria other than name, incl trees. It is a program. It starts 4 times to copy's 0. Starting programs is one of two main places where programming taxes are levied in Windows (other being Window creation).

Comment: Hi Noodles, thank you very much for the pointers. I will amend all to Copy and try it out :)

As for the suggestion of starting the EXE's hidden, unfortunately they require user interaction to complete (even though it is only a Next button click x 3) and I believe they will just cause the setup process to hang. Still, I'll give it a try and report back

Answer (score 0):

***Make sure that UAC is disabled before the setupcomplete.cmd runs.***

I use a stock Windows ISO to load Windows 10 on production machines and use:

- autounattend.xml to customize the install,
- setupcomplete.cmd to create an xml file which is then imported via schtasks.exe, then the imported
- Scheduled task to run a batch file to check that I have admin rights and a connection to my deployment server before starting my primary
- powershell script for the GUI customization.

When updating my deployed OS, I did not initially configure the autounattend.xml, and instead tested deployment using only the setupcomplete.cmd file as I had to insert the file into the image via DISM.  The Schtasks commands I had in the setupcomplete.cmd file would not run, but the rest of the batch file ran normally.

Just as others have experienced, the log file I was exporting the schtasks command output to was created, but had no content.  Additionally, the setupcomplete.bat would work properly without fail including the schtasks command when run manually.

After multiple tests, I found that when I ran the schtasks lines of the setupcomplete.cmd manually in an unelevated cmd prompt, I would get the same behavior as experienced when the setupcomplete.cmd is automatically triggered.

I was then able to confirm that my autounattend.xml file that I had not applied to my image does indeed disable UAC with the entry:

```html
    <settings pass="offlineServicing">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-LUA-Settings" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <EnableLUA>false</EnableLUA>
        </component>
    </settings>
```

Once I applied the autounattend.xml file to the deployed image with the setting shown, setupcomplete.cmd was able to successfully run the schtasks commands.